# capture snapshot with flash control

Tags: flash, screenshot

I would like to capture screenshots of the screen, convert it to a jpg and uploaded to the server using a flash control. I want something similar to what facebook has record a video, take a picture using your system's in-built web-cam, the main difference is that i want a screenshot of the system instead of the input from web-cam.

open to commercial controls as well. any links, examples would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Flash player doesn't have access to the system, only the content inside the flash player.

You could :

- Make a browser call to a java applet (using ExternalInterface)
- Consider something like merapi to run a java app on the desktop and get access to the broader system.

Comment: if flash player can access the web-cam installed on the system after explicit permission from user [eg. facebook], i am quite sure it can capture a screenshot and output it as jpg.

Comment: Marty is correct. But if you're so sure it can be done, why even ask?

Comment: The difference is that a webcam is a system object the flash player *explicitly grants* access to.

The desktop, system et al is a resource which is not.